# How to fetch subfolders with axios.get

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am new to React and Node. I am trying to display the contents of a folder based on the folder a user selects. Currently, this works for parent folders but does not work for subfolders. The axios.get on the client side does not work. Instead, I get a 404 (not found) error even though the path is correct. However, when I hardcode the path into the code, it works. I am wondering if the get for the subfolder is failing because of the "/".
The folder structure is as follows:
public_html/colllection:
- logos
-Test Folder
-anotherTestfolder
The error occurs for both subfolders of "logos"

Server.js code below

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { error } = require("console");
const cors = require("cors");
// const routes = require("./routes");
const fs = require("fs-extra");
const path = require("path");
const multer = require("multer");

const app = express();

// Middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());


// Function to get the folder structure

const getFolderStructure = async (folderPath) => {
  const folderName = path.basename(folderPath);
  const files = await fs.readdir(folderPath);
  // console.log(files);
  const folder = {
    name: folderName,
    files: [],
    children: [],
  };

  for (const file of files) {
    const filePath = path.join(folderPath, file);
    const stats = await fs.stat(filePath);

    if (stats.isFile()) {
      // console.log("file found");
      folder.files.push({
        name: file,
        type: path.extname(file).toLowerCase(),
        size: stats.size, // Size of the file in bytes
        lastModified: stats.mtime,
      });
    } else if (stats.isDirectory()) {
      const subFolder = await getFolderStructure(filePath);
      folder.children.push(subFolder);
    }
  }
  return folder;
};

// Route to get the folder structure
app.get("/api/folders", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const rootFolder = await getFolderStructure("../public_html/collection/");
    res.json(rootFolder);
    // console.log("response from serevr side for test", rootFolder);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching folder structure:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
  }
});

// getting forlder structure for selected file
app.get(`/api/folders/:folderName`, async (req, res) => {
  const folderName = req.params.folderName;
  // folderName = "logos/Test folder";
  console.log("from the server: ", folderName);
  try {
    console.log("this was the folder name", folderName);
    // console.log("back in the server with the selected folder", folderName);
    const folderPath = path.join("../public_html/collection/", folderName);
    console.log("here is the folder path", folderPath);
    const folderNameData = await getFolderStructure(folderPath);
    res.json(folderNameData);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching folder structure:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
  }
});
```

Body.js code below

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import axios from "axios";

function formatFileSize(sizeInBytes) {
  if (sizeInBytes >= 1024 * 1024) {
    return (sizeInBytes / (1024 * 1024)).toFixed(2) + " MB";
  } else if (isNaN(sizeInBytes)) {
    return "-";
  } else {
    return (sizeInBytes / 1024).toFixed(2) + " KB";
  }
}

// format the timestamp to a readable format for last modified timestamp
function formatModifiedDate(last_modified) {
  try {
    const date = new Date(last_modified); // Convert to Date object
    return new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", {
      year: "numeric",
      month: "short",
      day: "numeric",
      hour: "2-digit",
      minute: "2-digit",
    }).format(date);
  } catch (error) {
    // console.error("Error formatting modified date:", error);
    return "-"; // Return a default message for invalid dates
  }
}

const Body = () => {
  const [folderData, setFolderData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState(null);
  const [selectedFolder, setSelectedFolder] = useState(null);
  const [fileData, setFileData] = useState([]);
  const [currentPath, setCurrentPath] = useState("");
  const combinedContent = [];

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchFolderData();
  }, []);

  // connect to server to get the first set of folders
  const fetchFolderData = async () => {
    console.log("going to fetch folder data...");
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`/api/folders${currentPath}`);
      setFolderData(response.data.children);
      console.log("here is the response from server", response.data.children);
      //   console.log(response.data.children[0].files[1].type);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching folder data", error);
    }
  };

  const handleRowClick = async (params) => {
    const clickedFolderName = params.row.name;
    setSelectedFolder(clickedFolderName);
    console.log("this file was selected:", params.row.name);
    const newPath = currentPath
      ? `${currentPath}/${clickedFolderName}`
      : clickedFolderName;

    // handleFolderClick(clickedFolderName);
    try {
      console.log("trying to use this path", newPath);
      // const response = await axios.get(`/api/folders/${clickedFolderName}`);
      const response = await axios.get(`/api/folders/${newPath}`);
      console.log("this was the response: ", response);
      setFolderData(response.data.children);
      // Update the currentPath with the new path
      setCurrentPath(newPath);

      
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching folder data:", error);
      // console.error(error.response.data);
      // console.error(error.response.status);
      // console.error(error.response.headers);
    }
  };
  
  return (
    <div style={{ height: 500, width: "100%" }}>
      {/* {selectedFolder ? (
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => setSelectedFolder(null)}>Back</button>
          <FolderRow folder={selectedFolder} onRowClick={handleRowClick} />
        </div>
      ) : ( */}
      {/* {selectedFolder && <button onClick={handleBackClick}>Back</button>} */}

      <DataGrid
        rows={folderData.map((folder, index) => ({
          id: index, // Unique id for each folder row
          name: folder.name,
          type: folder.type,
          size: formatFileSize(folder.size),
          last_modified: formatModifiedDate(folder.last_modified),
        }))}
        columns={[
          { field: "name", headerName: "Name", width: 200 },
          { field: "type", headerName: "Type", width: 120 },
          { field: "size", headerName: "Size", width: 120 },
          { field: "last_modified", headerName: "Last Modified", width: 120 },
        ]}
        // onRowClick={(params) => handleEvent(folderData[params.rowIndex])}
        onRowClick={handleRowClick}
      />

      {/* {selectedFile && <FileRow file={selectedFile} />} */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Body;
```

Comment: You need a handler for `app.get(\`/api/folders/:folderName/:subfolderName\``. `/api/folders/logos/Test folder` won't trigger `app.get(\`/api/folders/:folderName\``.

Comment: Ideally, it should work for any number of subfolders at any level. Wouldn't this just only allow for one subfolder? What if I wanted a subfolder within a subfolder?

Comment: In that case you can't use route parameters